# converter strings em python

Tags: python, string, txt

Estou com dúvidas para resolver este exercício. Primeiramente, segue exemplo de arquivo txt.

```
5/2  
500+20   
200-20  
20*10
```

Eu preciso ler este arquivo txt e resolver as equações em Python.
Segue o código que possuo no momento.

```
arquivo = open("Calculadora lendo TXT.txt", 'r')  
for linha in arquivo:  
    linha = linha.strip()  
    print(linha)
```

Na minha lógica de iniciante, eu acredito que precise converter `string` para `INT` e saber como identificar os sinais das operações.

Comment: Cassio, você [acabou de fazer esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/426191/6333)... Seria melhor você editar sua pergunta anterior e melhorá-la.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importar arquivo Txt, ler e resolver as equações em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426191/importar-arquivo-txt-ler-e-resolver-as-equa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-em-python)

Answer (score 0):

Cassio, se você fizer o split na linha ela irá gerar um array de três posições, no qual da pra fazer as seguintes operações:

1 - Pegue o 1º e o 3º termo do array e converta-os para int(arr[posição]) - [Split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)
2 - Com a segunda posição do array você pode fazer um if com elif e colocar em alguma operação que queira. Soma, Subtração e multiplicação. - Link: [Condicionais](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else)

Acredito que isso já ajude a resolver esta questão.

Comment: e como ele faria o "split" sem conhecer o operador antes?

(dica - o correto aí é fazer uma leitor (parser) que leia caractere a caractere e tenha lógica para ler um número de n dígitos, um operador, e outro número, com espaços opcionais.  - pode ser feito com expressões regulares, mas a lógica caracter a caracter seria mais didática - e parece ser o objetivo do exercício)

Comment: A intenção de fazer o spilt é para quebrar em um array de três posições, para possa usar o vetor para realizar a operação, realmente com expressão regular dava para fazer, mas o que quis apontar é um forma mais simples e didática de resolver.

Answer (score -1):

Eu resolveria assim:

```
with open('Calculadora lendo TXT.txt') as arquivo:
   for linha in arquivo:
       print(f'{linha}: {eval(linha)}')
```

Usando o "with" você não se preocupa em ter que fechar o arquivo após usa-lo.
A linha do "for" não mudei nada.
Usei formatação de string para dar print. A primeira variável é informando mostrando a conta que será realizada, é colocado ":" e depois uso a função "eval" que executa a conta. Note que para funcionar as contas devem usar o padrão do Python, como por exemplo "**" para elevar a potência. Para o exemplo dado funciona para todos.

Comment: o uso do Eval é um "curto circuito" que invalida o propósito do exercício - apesar de funcionar nesse caso.

Comment: A minha ideia era arranjar solução no Python, não solução de exercício de algorítimo. O problema então é algorítimo e deveria estar com esse tag. Mas entendi o ponto de vista. Python tem muitos atalhos que realmente não deve ser utilizados quando a ideia é exercitar algorítimo.